# Insert data from Oracle into Java Object

Tags: java, oracle

I have this two column table which I use to store settings as key and value:

```
SETTINGNAME VARCHAR2(40 BYTE)
SETTINGVALUE    VARCHAR2(40 BYTE)
```

And I have this Java Object which I want to use to store the values from the Oracle table:

```
public class DataObj {

        private String sessionTTL;
        private int maxUsersActive;
        private String timestampFormat;
        private int initState;
        private String logFileName;
        private String logDirectory;
        private int logBufferSize;
        private String logLevel;
.......
}
```

The question is how I can insert the values from the table into the Java object. I always have fixed number of returned values. In this case how I can insert the values into the Object?

Comment: How would you describe how the information should be put in Oracle and restore back in the object?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your question is rather broad. You can query the database with JDBC and then manually put the values in an object. This is rather low level. Or you can use an ORM like DataNucleus and have the ORM query the database and populate the Java objects for you. This is more high level.

Comment: You are probably looking for something that isn't there. There is no one line of code you can use out of the box to grab data from a database and put it into a Java object; It is not part of standard Java. You can try an ORM like the JPA standard: http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/tutorial/doc/bnbpz.html